# WP All Import manual Cron

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, import, wp-cron, cron, xml

I am having problem to set up Cron to import stock. In Plugin WP-All Import i have two urls. One which starts import, another one is checking process and if it's stuck it kicks it back on.

I'm runing website on cpanel and i tried everything i found on internet. I keep getting 503 error. But when i go to link it works. Do you have any expiriences with WP All import and C-panel cron anyone?

My last settings i tried:

[image: Last settings]

But i got 503 error.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

You can try like this:

wget -q -O /dev/null "https://example.com/wp-load.php?import_key=123xyz&import_id=YOURID&action=trigger"

**[From the documentation](https://www.wpallimport.com/documentation/recurring/cron/)**

Each import has two cron URLs – a trigger URL, and a processing URL.

The trigger URL will look something like this:
[http://YOUR-WEBSITE.com/wp-load.php?import_key=[YOUR_SECRET_KEY]&import_id=[YOUR_IMPORT_ID]&action=trigger](http://YOUR-WEBSITE.com/wp-load.php?import_key=%5BYOUR_SECRET_KEY%5D&import_id=%5BYOUR_IMPORT_ID%5D&action=trigger)

The processing URL will look something like this:
[http://YOUR-WEBSITE.com/wp-load.php?import_key=[YOUR_SECRET_KEY]&import_id=[YOUR_IMPORT_ID]&action=processing](http://YOUR-WEBSITE.com/wp-load.php?import_key=%5BYOUR_SECRET_KEY%5D&import_id=%5BYOUR_IMPORT_ID%5D&action=processing)

You can find your secret key on the All Import -> Settings screen, and the import ID on the Manage Imports screen.

If you want to run your import every 24 hours, you should run the trigger URL every 24 hours. If you want to run your import once per week, you should run the trigger URL every week.

The processing URL should be run every two minutes because it may not finish your import in one run. The reason is that many hosts have maximum script execution times in place, so its only possible for the processing script to finish only a small percentage of your import before it is timed out.

If this is the case and the processing script is run again after two minutes, it checks to see if your import is finished, or if there’s still work to be done. If there’s work to be done, it will import posts for as long as it can, or two minutes, whichever is longer.

Then, on the next run of the processing script, it will see if more work needs to be done on the import – and if so, it will do it. If not, it will “untrigger” the import. And now the processing script will have no effect until the import is triggered again by the next run of the trigger script.

Setting Up Cron Jobs

The instructions for setting up cron jobs vary across hosts. Commonly, you can do it in your web hosting control panel.

To create a cron job that hits the cron URLs, commonly the wget command is used. Examples are on the Manage Imports -> Cron Scheduling screen of
WP All Import.

Below are a few cron command examples (not all options work with all hosts, ask your host for help as needed):

```
wget --spider "http://YOUR-WEBSITE.com/wp-load.php?import_key=[YOUR_SECRET_KEY]&import_id=[YOUR_IMPORT_ID]&action=trigger&rand="$RANDOM
Bash
wget -q -O - "http://YOUR-WEBSITE.com/wp-load.php?import_key=[YOUR_SECRET_KEY]&import_id=[YOUR_IMPORT_ID]&action=trigger&rand="$RANDOM
Bash
curl "http://YOUR-WEBSITE.com/wp-load.php?import_key=[YOUR_SECRET_KEY]&import_id=[YOUR_IMPORT_ID]&action=trigger&rand="$RANDOM
Bash
lynx "http://YOUR-WEBSITE.com/wp-load.php?import_key=[YOUR_SECRET_KEY]&
```